# Viewing http requests that happened

Tags: networking, server, history, logs

Is there a log file where ubuntu stores all the http requests that come in?
I need to view a request that happened yesterday, more specifically the body of that POST request.

And also if nothing is listening on that port would that be a problem? The port is open by the firewall there is just no application that is using that port. Would that be a problem when it comes to viewing the requests

Comment: That depends on the service running. See `/var/log/` for all logs and the sub directory `apache/` if apache. If mysql see subdirectory `mysql/`. Your router will also have a log.

Comment: If you are using Apache as the web server, POST bodies are not logged by default. It would need to be something that you specifically configured, as POST bodies may contain passwords or other sensitive data, and the logs are plain text 